# protobuf is storing data in octal form for non english field value

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

While storing a non-English string in Protobuf, it stores it in octal form.

```
answer_proto.attribute_answer.attribute_name = 'सियार'

print(answer_proto)
```

results to:

> attribute_answer {   attribute_name:
>   "\340\244\270\340\244\277\340\244\257\340\244\276\340\244\260" }

Comment: Don't worry. The representation in memory is still binary and correct. Octal is only the printable representation in the string literal.

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianW. Yes, I understand, but while sending this answer_proto using grpc response, it displays octal code rather than a string

Comment: You probably have an encoding problem. Are you using Python2 or 3? In Python2 strings are bytes, but in Python3, strings are Unicode. If I say `'सियार'` in a Python console, then Python3 shows the plain text, but Python2 shows `'\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0'`, which is the same as your octal string. Still wondering why you have octal, because the default representation of non-ASCII chas is hex.

Comment: I am using python3. When i do, print(answer_proto.attribute_answer.attribute_name), it gives me 'सियार', but if print(answer_proto) it gives me the string in its octal form. Do I need to mention some explicit encoding types for protos?